# Unable to use boolean values in IF statements

Tags: java, android, if-statement, boolean

I have a database that is being checked using a Cursor. This database compares the data in the database to the user entered username and password. If they match data in the database a boolean is returned true. I can use a toast to output the boolean which correctly outputs as true or false if the input data does or does not match.

However, i am trying to use the boolean to move to the next activity. If the boolean is true the next intent is started. This does not work for some reason and I cant seem to work out why. Any help would be great. Thanks!

```
public Button btnLogin, btnSignup;
public EditText UsernameInput, PasswordInput;
public DatabaseHelper db;
public static String passUser, passPass, passFirst, passSecond;
public int count;
public Boolean matchingUser = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Align page and remove notification bar
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

    // Define everything
    btnLogin =  findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnSignup =  findViewById(R.id.btnSignup);
    UsernameInput =  findViewById(R.id.UsernameInput);
    PasswordInput =  findViewById(R.id.PasswordInput);
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    // validation button
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            validateLogin(UsernameInput.getText().toString(), PasswordInput.getText().toString());
        }
    });
    btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CreateUser();
        }
    });
}
// Validation code
public void validateLogin(String userName, String userPassword)
{
    if (userName.equals("")|| userPassword.equals(""))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Fields are empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        // CHECKING USER LOGIN DETAILS
        Cursor cursor = db.CompareUserData();
        for (count = 0; count<=cursor.getCount();count++)
        {
            if (cursor.moveToPosition(count))
            {
                if (UsernameInput.getText().toString().equals(cursor.getString(0))&&PasswordInput.getText().toString().equals(cursor.getString(1)))
                {
                    matchingUser = true;
                }
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, "boolean : "+ matchingUser, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (matchingUser = true)
            {
                passUser = cursor.getString(0);
                passPass = cursor.getString(1);
                passFirst = cursor.getString(2);
                passSecond = cursor.getString(3);

                getUser();
                getPass();
                getFirst();
                getSecond();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                LoginValidation(); 
            }

            if (matchingUser = false)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Incorrect Username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }}
    }
}
private void LoginValidation()
{
    // Changing activity code
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Login_Biometrics.class));
}
private void CreateUser()
{
    // Changing activity code
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,createUser.class));
}
public static String getUser ()
{

    return passUser;
}
public static String getPass ()
{


    return passPass;
}
public static String getFirst ()
{

    return passFirst;
}
public static String getSecond ()
{


    return passSecond;


}
```

Comment: Side note: Please don't store clear text passwords in your database.

Comment: you have to ask: if (matchinguser == false), otherwise you set matchinguser to false. Same for the "true" handling

Comment: Please don't edit posts to change the question so that it doesn't match the answers, especially accepted answers.  If there's more information to be added, it should be appended, not replace the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont work with one = equal sign just do:

```
if(matchingUser) {
  // if true do something
} else {
  // if false do something
}
```

In your case:

```
if (matchingUser) {
   passUser = cursor.getString(0);
   passPass = cursor.getString(1);
   passFirst = cursor.getString(2);
   passSecond = cursor.getString(3);

   getUser();
   getPass();
   getFirst();
   getSecond();
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully logged in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   LoginValidation(); 
} else {
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Incorrect Username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Ive attempted to all three versions with the same outcome. =, ==, and matchingUser

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand some basics:

**Assignment operator `=`**

Is used to assign value to some variable.

**Logical operator `==`**

Is used to make some logical comparison.

So instead of doing this:

```
if (matchingUser = true)
{
...
```

Do this

```
if (matchingUser == true)
{
...
```

Apply this for every condition checking in your code.

Comment: on clicking the button it returned the toast as true however did not move to the next activity.

Comment: If the toast returns true, it means your problem is solved.

Comment: No i was able to return the toast true already. but for some reason the if statement was not functioning.

Comment: If the Toast is showing **Successfully logged in** it means your condition is true. Any thing you need beyond that is out of the context of your question.

Comment: No so the boolean is showing as true but the toast for logged in and the intent to next activity were not functioning

Comment: almost as if the boolean wasnt correct or it was being ignored

Comment: Look if the condition is written in a true format, and when the if statement doesn't execute it means the condition is false thats it, and it wont run until the condition becomes true.

Comment: It was solved by moving the passUser etc methods to the if statement comparing the username. This along with the boolean fixed the problem. thanks anyway